# In Facebook Graph API, what are the API calls to get a user's email address and gender?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Graph API and the Facebook SDK for PHP with the help of this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0. This is the code:

```
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

if($session) {

  try {

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
```

I'm at the point where I'm able to get a user's name by using `user_profile->getName();`, I can also get his/her first name, last name, middle name, etc., according to the API calls here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/#user-instance-methods. I know it is possible to get a user's email address and gender, but in the previous link I didn't find any API calls to be able to get this information.

For Facebook SDK for PHP, what are the API calls to get a user's email address and gender?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fields

to get an overview what fields and edges you can query for the user object. In your case, that should be

```
/me?fields=id,gender,email
```

or

```
new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,gender,email'
)
```

Be aware that you'll need the `user_email` permission to be able to request the `email` field.

To get specific fields, use the `getProperty()` method as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/#getproperty

```
echo $user_profile->getProperty('gender');
```

Comment: In the Approved Items section of my app, it says this about Login permissions: "email: Provides access to the person's primary email address. This permission is approved by default." and "public_profile: Provides access to a person's basic information, including first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range. This permission is approved by default." Therefore, I thought I had the permissions for email and gender by default. So my question is, what do you mean by `user_email` permission?

Comment: And my other question is, what is the API call to get email and gender (e.g., like `$user_profile->getName()`)? I cannot find that anywhere.

Comment: Yes, `user_email` permission is granted by default. But you need to request it in the login permissions scope when you're calling the login link. Updated my answer, but it's all in the docs already!